# Maximizing a sum of Gaussians

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

Let $\mathbf{x}_1, \dots, \mathbf{x}_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be $n$ given vectors. Define the function

$$ \mathcal{K}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) := \alpha\exp\left(-\frac{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$

where $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ are given constants. Now define the $n\times 1$ vector

$$ \mathcal{K}_n(\mathbf{x}) := \begin{bmatrix} \mathcal{K}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}_1) & \dots & \mathcal{K}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}_n) \end{bmatrix}^\top $$

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be any $n \times n$ positive definite matrix and $\mathbf{b}$ be any $n \times 1$ real vector. Let $\lambda > 0$ be given. Consider the optimization problem

$$ \max_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d} \quad\mathcal{K}_n(\mathbf{x})^\top\mathbf{b}-\lambda\mathcal{K}_n(\mathbf{x})^\top\mathbf{A}\mathcal{K}_n(\mathbf{x}) $$

Is this optimization problem known in literature? How do I do gradient ascent on this?

Comment: yes, still interested in it. I had given up any attempts on it though :).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any connection between your problem and MPC.

Take a look at optimization via the technique known as stochastic approximation; it is extremely popular today for several reasons. Check out "Optimization Methods for Large-Scale Machine Learning" by Bottou, Curtis, and Nocedal on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04838, especially Section 3.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a stochastic optimizer [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization).

This optimization is stochastic. Thus, it requires you optimize the expectation $E[.]$ of a particular value.

In an engineering problem, they often have some constraint on top of optimization which form a stochastic programming problem [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_programming)[[3]](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/people/faculty/Alex_Shapiro/TutorialSP.pdf)[[4]](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~jrbirge/html/dholmes/StoProIntro.html). In such problems, the constraints also become stochastic.

I refer you to a great publication on Stochastic Model Predictive Control:

- Mesbah, A., 2016. Stochastic model predictive control: An overview and perspectives for future research. IEEE Control Systems, 36(6), pp.30-44. [[5]](https://cloudfront.escholarship.org/dist/prd/content/qt1wt3d4vr/qt1wt3d4vr.pdf)

To make the life easy, you can use a *Monte Carlo* method with a bunch of scenarios to perform an optimization. I refere you to a few publications:

- Janson, L., Schmerling, E. and Pavone, M., 2018. Monte Carlo motion planning for robot trajectory optimization under uncertainty. In Robotics Research (pp. 343-361). Springer, Cham. [[6]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.08053.pdf)
- Maldonado, D.A., 2017. Sequential Monte Carlo Methods for Parameter Estimation, Dynamic State Estimation and Control in Power Systems (Doctoral dissertation). [[7]](http://repository.iit.edu/handle/10560/4176)
- Oldewurtel, F., Jones, C.N., Parisio, A. and Morari, M., 2014. Stochastic model predictive control for building climate control. IEEE Transactions on Control Systems Technology, 22(3), pp.1198-1205. [[8]](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/190572/files/06573317.pdf)

Comment: Why am I looking at stochastic optimization. There is nothing random here. Everything is deterministic.

Comment: @dineshdileep. I see. How do you know this optimization is positive definite? Is it is not positive definite, a gradient descent does not necessarily work. Then, you may go after evolutionary-based methods such as Genetic Algorithm (GA).